# Delete local folder when project is deleted in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We just started using TFS and it works great. I have one question though, if we delete a folder it's not deleted on my local workspace. We are currently reorganizing a project and I wish to not have heaps of unused folders on my local drive.

Where can I configure this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when you delete a folder in Visual Studio the folder on disk is not removed?

Comment: The local folders are not deleted when they are not empty (or better said: not all files are under source control). This is the case when you have binaries in bin\debug for example.

Answer (score 3):

In you have the Visual Studio Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) you can use the command line tools tfpt to clean up all your workspaces.

In a shell window

- change directory to your workspace root
- type \tfpt.exe treeclean /recurse .

This will remove any file or folder not in source control.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which also checks how well your project is put together, is to cut the whole folder and move it elsewhere, then perform a get across the project.  This will allow you to check if the project will build or if there are some "magic" DLLs missing.  Anything that is missing can be retrieved from the copy of the structure and added into source control.